# Should branching of functions be tested if not part of the contract?

Tags: unit-testing

Let's assume I have a method that performs an internal operation just the first time it gets called, e.g.:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this._unlocked = false;
    this._data = null;
  }
  bar() {
    if (!this._unlocked) {
      this._unlock();
    }
    ...
    return true;
  }
  _unlock() {
    performSomeUnlockOperation();
    this._unlocked = true;
  }
}
```

The contract of the `bar` method does not expose its internals, so it is enough to unit test it once per case, e.g.:

```
const foo = new Foo();
expect(foo.bar()).toReturn(true);
```

This way, the coverage tools would tell me that I skipped the `if` branch.

Is this a bad design smell?

From one side, it violates the single responsibility principle - `bar` is now doing two things, unlocking and its own stuff. Should I then wrap this object in a further external object that controls the unlock state? The point is that I do not want to expose the `_unlock()` call for external consumers all the time.

TL;DR what is the tradeoff between testability and API complexity in this case?

EDIT: the unlock operation is to request focus before reproducing audio via Web Audio API - i.e. to play a short 0 amplitude sample before playing the actual sound.

Comment: should _unlock set _unlocked to true at the end?

Comment: Can you add information about why the `if` branch exists? If deleting it would not make tests fail, would it cause a problem for users?

Answer (score 2):

Tests should be useful. Coverage alone doesn't make a test useful or not, but incomplete coverage can hint at useful tests.

Viewed from the outside, that unlock mechanism may or may not matter – it depends. It would be perfectly fine if the “contract” for this class describes that the object has locked and unlocked states, if that is relevant. It's also perfectly fine if this is hidden from outside view. Then, the `bar()` operation would be expected to always succeed and sort out this unlocking internally.

But from the perspective of a developer working on this class, we might very well like white-box tests that explicitly cover this branch. The unlocked state that may be hidden from the outside is now very relevant. Tests that verify that the `bar()` operation works in all states of the objects could be useful.

Such developer tests tend to require a very testable design or deeper access into the internals, but this looks like JavaScript. Setting `foo._unlocked = true` from the outside is fairly fragile, but that might be a good tradeof if this test is valuable.

A more general pattern is to design APIs in two layers:
first a layer that contains the core logic and is easy to test,
and above that a thin layer that wraps this logic in a public API.
Here, your lower layer might implement a generic initialize-once object, so that the main object doesn't even need any branches.

Answer (score 2):

If it is valid to test that a function works when it is called once, it is also valid to test that it works when it is called twice. And if you *know* that the internal behaviour on the second call is different, then it is common sense that there are bugs that only show up on the second call, or only on the first call. So it's absolutely fine to test it twice.

What if you don't? First, if the code of the function is changed, and bugs are introduced only on the codepath for the second call, your unit test wouldn't find it. Second, if your actual code calls the function twice and fails, you'll rely on the unit test and think the function is always correct, making it so much harder to find a bug.

Answer (score 1):

### How to test private members

Every private member that is useful, is used in some way by a public behavior of that class. To put it another way: if a private member's existence/value has zero impact on a class' public behavior in any way, then it can be safely removed.

Therefore, by fully testing your class' public behavior, you will invariably always be testing all *useful* private members. Since all other (and thus untested) private members can and should be safely removed, this means all your (remaining) private members will have been tested.

In your case:

- `performSomeUnlockOperation` could cause a change in state somewhere external to the class. That behavior can be tested, by mocking the object whose state gets altered and seeing if it was altered in the expected way.
- `performSomeUnlockOperation` could be changing the internal state of the class, which in turn causes its public behavior to change. That behavior (of `performSomeUnlockOperation`) can be tested by confirming that your class has the correct altered public behavior after having called `performSomeUnlockOperation`.

If `performSomeUnlockOperation` does not change any state external to the class, and only changes state internally in a way that does not change the public behavior of that class, then we can refer back to my initial point and conclude that `performSomeUnlockOperation` is useless and can be safely removed.

---

### Should we test private branching logic?

No, not explicitly. We test public behavior. Private logic branching may be part of the implementation required to achieve the desired public behavior, but **we do not test the implementation, we test the public behavior**.

Take this simple example:

```
public class Calculator
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        if(a < b)
            return a + b;
        else
            return (2*a + 2*b) / 2;
    }
}
```

Clearly, I've added a private logical branch that isn't necessary (the first option would work in all cases). The second option actually yields the same result, it just calculated it using a slightly different method.

The point I'm trying to get across here is that **this class would pass any test that a more straightforward `return a + b;` implementation would also pass**. The manner of implementation is irrelevant as far as the test is concerned. What matter is the public behavior, i.e. if the number that gets returned is actually the sum of the numbers that were given.

---

As a smaller aside, the SRP consideration is completely separate from this question, and there's not enough information in the question to answer that as well. There is not enough information here for me to conclude whether the unlocking functionality is a discrete responsibility or not.

And it doesn't really matter to the main question. If not part of the class itself, it's still a dependency that gets injected. The way of testing it will change, but what doesn't change is that **your tests don't explicitly test private branching logic.**